# Created an Angular Provider and now getting StaticInjectorError

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, dependency-injection

I was building a new angular (v6.0.1) application and wanted to start wiring it up to handle data through a service. I created a new provider as below:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class NewsRepositoryProvider {
    constructor(private firebase: AngularFireDatabase) {

    }

    ///Gets a news article starting at a certain index and then so many forward
    public getPagedNews(start: number, count: number): AngularFireList<any> {
        return this.firebase.list('/News/');
    }
}
```

Wanting to make certain this stub worked before I really dived into it, I wired it up and added it to a component constructor:

AppModule:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavMenuComponent,
        NewsComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        ContactComponent,
        ProductsComponent,
        ApplicationsComponent,
        NewsRepositoryProvider,
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'applications', component: ApplicationsComponent },
            { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent },
            { path: 'news', component: NewsComponent },
            { path: 'products', component: ProductsComponent },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
        ]),
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(FIREBASE_CONFIG),
        AngularFireAuthModule,
        AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    ],
})
export class AppModuleShared {
}
```

Component:

```
constructor(private newsRepo: NewsRepositoryProvider) {    
        console.log(newsRepo.getPagedNews(0, 10));    
    }
```

I run webpack and then launch the page. To my surprise I get the following error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
NodeInvocationException: StaticInjectorError(e)[LocationStrategy -> PlatformLocation]: 
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[LocationStrategy -> PlatformLocation -> InjectionToken DocumentToken]: 
Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object
TypeError: StaticInjectorError(e)[LocationStrategy -> PlatformLocation]: 
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[LocationStrategy -> PlatformLocation -> InjectionToken DocumentToken]: 
Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object
at bt (\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:109:67471)
```

I've been pouring over StackOverflow questions, trying to determine what could be the root cause of this error. Anyone familiar with the error? Did I do something wrong in setting up the service?

Comment: remove the `providers: [NewsRepositoryProvider]` declaration in your module.

Comment: I tried this but the error didn't change.

Comment: have you imported AngularFireDatabase related modules in your app

Answer (score 1):

Angular version 6 comes with new way to inject your service for the tree shaking feature so you can use the old one with is add it to the provider array inside your module like this:

```
providers: [
   NewsRepositoryProvider
]
```

Or inside the service class like this:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
```

So you should use one of them and i suggest using the way inside your service.

Comment: I removed the module declaration and kept the @injectable declaration, but the stack trace is still the same

Comment: Could you please provide me with your `AppModule` code.

Comment: Your module looks fine, after that i noticed that the error is in your `main.js` file as the error says `Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object
at bt (\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:109:67471)` so i assume you are using node js for server side right? try to update your nodejs version or check the mentioned line in your main-server.js file.

Comment: main-server.js is the bundled webpack javascript. I'll update my package.json and see what happens, though.